# How to view a big picture by dragging on Android? Just like we do on Google Maps

Tags: android, imageview

I've being trying this all night through.    Is there any good solution to do this? Having a sample code is better!

Comment: Can you post what you have tried?

Comment: If you want to scroll a really big picture (horizontally AND vertically) there is no real simple solution, you must implement some own javacode. For example: https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/custom-scrollable-image-view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question, after a loooong time.

I finally found a solution, just use the WebView, to load the image in the browser inside the WebView, Android then did everything for me!